# Example of using unfloat::[] macro in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I have the following markup in AsciiDoc:

```
[[filter-example]]
.Filters are created through matrix operations
image::figs/filter_example.png[scaledwidth="90%"]
```

I would like to use the `unfloat::[]` macro with this image, but I haven't been able to find any examples of how to do it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[A Block macro reference must be contained in a single line separated either side by a blank line or a block delimiter.](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/asciidoc.html#_block_macros)

Use the unfloat-blockmacro before or after the image-blockmacro, f.e. like this:

```
unfloat::[] 
[[filter-example]] 
.Filters are created through matrix operations    
image::figs/filter_example.png["alt text", scaledwidth="90%"]
```

In a default AsciiDoc installation, the unfloat-blockmacro has effect to the html backends only. In the xhtml11-backend, the example code will be translated to

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>        <!-- line was added by using unfloat::[] -->
<div id="filter-example" class="imageblock">
<div class="content">
<img alt="alt text" src="filter_example.png">
</div>
<div class="image-title">Abbildung 1: Filters are created through matrix operations</div>
</div>
```

In file asciidoc.conf you will find a definition without implementation for the unfloat-blockmacro:

```
[unfloat-blockmacro]
# Implemented in HTML backends.
```

In file html4.conf you will find the unfloat implementation for html backends:

```
[unfloat-blockmacro]
<br clear="all">
```

In file xhtml11.conf you will find the unfloat implemention for xhtml backends:

```
[unfloat-blockmacro]
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Change these lines if you expect an other result in your html-backend.